# spring mvc web application deployed on JBoss as 7.1.1.Final can not access using localhost

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss7.x

I have been trying to get access my spring mvc application deployed on JBoss as 7.1.1 but I got 404.

The following is the last few lines of my deployment log

```
 21:57:07,627 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/esm]] (MSC service thread 1-8) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
21:57:07,628 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-8) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
21:57:07,644 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-8) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 15 ms
21:57:07,646 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /esm
21:57:07,735 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 3) JBAS018559: Deployed "esm.war"
```

According to the log, it is successfully deployed.

and in the folder /standalone/deployments/esm.war.deployed

So, all this is good enough to get my app up and running. But I have no idea why I am getting 404.

I tried to get access as follow:

http://localhost:8080/esm

Could someone point me out where exactly I did go wrong?
could it be that it is not pointing to the correct folder?

@ Tomcat, all the deployed web folder can be found at
/var/lib/tomcat(7)/webapp/

is there such thing like this in JBoss?

Comment: Plz provide ur spring mvc project specific **configuration** details.

Comment: it is there now

https://github.com/yasoe31/esm_health

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide bind address when starting the server.

```
standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0
```

or

```
standalone.bat -b hostname
```